# Typescript Uncaught TypeError while extending SVGTextElement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a simple extension for SVGTextElement, here it is:

```
interface SVGTextElement {
    setX(value: string): SVGTextElement;
    setY(value: string): SVGTextElement;
}

SVGTextElement.prototype.setX = (value: string): SVGTextElement => {
    var el: SVGTextElement = this;
    el.setAttribute("x", value);
    return el;
}

SVGTextElement.prototype.setY = (value: string): SVGTextElement => {
    var el: SVGTextElement = this;
    el.setAttribute("y", value);
    return el;
}
```

I am using this extension like this:

```
const e = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
e.setX("0");
```

But I am getting error:

> SvgTextElementExtensions.ts:18 Uncaught TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: given that `el` is an instance of `SVGTextElement` and this doesn't have any method called `setAttribute` you will obviously get this error. Don't forget that you use typescript to have your types checked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the fat arrow syntax here, that will bind `this` to window, and window does not have `setAttribute`. Do this:

```
SVGTextElement.prototype.setX = function (value: string): SVGTextElement {
    var el: SVGTextElement = this;
    el.setAttribute("x", value);
    return el;
}

SVGTextElement.prototype.setY = function (value: string): SVGTextElement {
    var el: SVGTextElement = this;
    el.setAttribute("y", value);
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your approach works fine! I didn't know about the difference between simple functions and arrow functions.